# How to set the cwd(current working directory) in Vscode

Tags: c++

I'm starting to use vscode for C++. I have a simple test program. I want to run it under debug and I need to set the working directory for the run.

How/where do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In debug configuaration, `cwd` specifies currect directory when running debugged application:

```
        {
            "name": "debug profile",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/home/asd/asd.o",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: So does it not have a value that I can input in cwd for any project

Comment: @MOSESAMAECHI I don't know if there is such a value. since I need to make debug profile for debugging my application anyway, it does not differ to add another attribute for `cwd` to it or not.